# UIWebView sizeThatsFit works incorrect with 64bit

Tags: ios, uiwebview, 64-bit

I have got a strange behaviour in my app with a webview. I have a string with html code. I put it into the webview.
In webViewDidFinishLoad I resize the webview. This works fine for a long time. 
Now I convert my app to 64bit.
The webview works still fine with 32bit iPhones (iPhone4 for example). 
With a 64bit iPhone (iPhone6 or simulators) in the majority of cases the calculated height is ok, but sometimes it is 1, everytime the same content.

```
-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView{
[aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';  document.body.style.KhtmlUserSelect='none'"];

CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
frame.size.height = 1;
frame.size.width = aWebView.superview.frame.size.width-frame.origin.x*2;
aWebView.frame = frame;
CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:frame.size];
fittingSize.width = aWebView.superview.frame.size.width-frame.origin.x*2;
frame.size = fittingSize;
aWebView.frame = frame;
}
```

Can someone help me why the sizeThatFits sometimes not working correct?

Comment: screenshot will help to provide answer here.

Comment: Sorry cant post a screenshot, cause of copyright problems. The html content is a simple table with texts. In case its doing wrong, you just see nothing from html content.